# How can I stop javascript that is not required for the page showing errors?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript file for my site that looks like this (it runs a simple slideshow on my homepage, and a gallery on my Gallery page):

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

var slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slideshow .slide');
var currentSlide = 0;
var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,4000);

function nextSlide() {
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
    currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
    slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}

if(slides) {
  nextSlide();
}

});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  lightGallery(document.getElementById('lightgallery'));
});
```

On other pages on my site (e.g. Contact) there is no slideshow, but all pages load the same javascript file. Now in my console on pages without the slideshow I am getting the following message:

> TypeError: slides[currentSlide] is undefined

My question is how do I keep loading a single javascript file for my site, while avoiding parts of it that are not required for the currently viewed page showing errors like this? Ideally I would like to not define the pages in the javascript file so I have flexibility of what content I put on each page.

Comment: just remove the loading of the file in the other pages then

Comment: Wasn't there a global consensus that slideshows are the worst thing people are putting on webpages since `<marquee>`?

Comment: `if(slides)` must be `if(slides.length)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for length of the slides variable which is array.

```
if(slides.length > 0) {
  ...
}
```